# Counting the number of occurrences of chars in one string, in another string

Tags: java, strings

This program counts the total number of times any character from the source string can be found in the target string.

E.g Source String - `"Hello World"`
Target String - `"llo"`
Output = `5` (as there are 3 `l`'s and 2 `o`'s)

Source String - `"Hello World"`
Target String - `"ooood"`
Output = `3` (as there are 2 `o`'s and 1 `d`)

Is there any better way of write the below program?

```
public class CountOccurence {
public static int countChars(String target, String source){
    char a[] = source.toCharArray();

    int loc = 0, count = 0;
    boolean charRepeat = false;

    for (loc = 0; loc < source.length(); loc++) {
        charRepeat = false;
        for (int z = 0; z < loc; z++) {
            if (a[loc] == a[z]) {
                charRepeat = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (charRepeat == false) {
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = target.indexOf(a[loc], i)) != -1) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String target = "Hello World";
    String source = "oood";

    int count = countChars(target, source);
    System.out.println(count);

    source = "lld";
    count = countChars(target, source);
    System.out.println(count);

}

}
```

Comment: to reduce confusion, the source string should just be a set of characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Style

There are a few bad habits in here that should be resolved. Here's your core method:

> ```
> public static int countChars(String target, String source){
>     char a[] = source.toCharArray();
>
>     int loc = 0, count = 0;
>     boolean charRepeat = false;
>
>     for (loc = 0; loc < source.length(); loc++) {
>         charRepeat = false;
>         for (int z = 0; z < loc; z++) {
>             if (a[loc] == a[z]) {
>                 charRepeat = true;
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>
>         if (charRepeat == false) {
>             int i = 0;
>             while ((i = target.indexOf(a[loc], i)) != -1) {
>                 count++;
>                 i++;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return count;
> }
> ```

let's go through some things that are style-based.

- source comes before target. The natural thinking is that you go from the source to the target, your naming, and the order of the parameters, is awkward. I would call the `source` something like `searchFor`, and the `target` I would call `searchIn`. Note, you have confused these values so much that your description does not match your code. In your description you have:

  > ```
  > E.g Source String - "Hello World"
  > Target String - "ooood"
  > Output = 3
  > ```

  but in your code you have:

  > ```
  > String target = "Hello World";
  > String source = "oood";
  > int count = countChars(target, source);
  > ```

  Note how you have swapped the source/target between the example and the code.

  `source` and `target` are basically bad names to have...
- Your code uses a number of small variables that are unconventional. `loc` is not a terrible name, it is clearly short for `location`, but using the fill `location` would be better. I have a habit of using `pos` so I can't really complain. On the other hand, the variables `a` for the char array, and `z` for an index, are bad names. You already use `charRepeat`, so you know how to use meaningful names, use them. The `z` is interesting because it is common to use x, y, and z as names for coordinate space, so seeing `z` automatically implies there's an x and y too. You should rather just use the standard index variables `i`, `j`, and `k` (but don't use `j` unless you are already using `i`, and don't use `k` unless you are using `j` too).

### Algorithm

Your algorithm is a bit messed up too. Basically, you scan the `searchFor` chars, and find the first occurrence of each char value. If it's the first one, you then use that to scan the `searchIn` value, and you count the 'hits' in there. There are two issues here. The first issue is the performance of the 'first check'. The performance is \$O(n^2)\$ where \$n\$ is the number of chars in the `searchFor` value.

Then, for each unique char, you then do a loop through all the `searchIn` chars. The loop through all those are disguised in two steps, first the while loop, and then inside that, the `indexOf` search.

The net result is that you have a performance of \$O(nm)\$ or \$O(n^2)\$ depending on whether there are more characters in the `searchIn` or `searchFor` strings.

There is a better solution for both the uniqueness testing, and for the searching. Consider sorting the chars in each string:

```
char[] lookFor = searchFor.toCharArray();
char[] lookIn = searchIn.toCharArray();

Arrays.sort(lookFor);
Arrays.sort(lookIn);
```

The two sorts are \$O(n \log n)\$ performance, so this is, so far, significantly less complicated... now, how do we compare? Well, with a 'simple' loop over all the lookIn characters:

```
int forpos = 0;
int count = 0;
for (char c : lookIn) {
    // advance the searchFor cursor to the next usable position
    while (forpos < lookFor.length && lookFor[forpos] < c) {
        forpos++;
    }
    if (forpos >= lookFor.length) {
        //nothing left to look for.
        break;
    }
    if (c == lookFor[forpos]) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
```

With the above code, you do two sorts, and 1 loop through each value. The net result is that your performance complexity is simply \$O(n \log n)\$ where \$n\$ is the longer of the `searchIn` or `searchFor` variables.

By sorting each side, you give yourself a significant algorithmic advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Use a set containing the characters of the target string:

```
public static int countChars(String target, String source)
{
    int count = 0;

    Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();

    for (char c : target.toCharArray())
        if (!charSet.contains(c))
            charSet.add(c);

    for (char c : source.toCharArray())
        if (charSet.contains(c))
            count++;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: There is no point in checking `charSet.contains(c)` before doing `charSet.add(c)`. Sets will automatically deduplicate members.

Comment: @200_success: I know that. I added it there in order to make it easier for OP to understand.

Answer (score 1):

your way of doing this seems kinda weird to me:

Source "hello world" target "llo"

first create a set for the target, which contains only characters from the target, in this example l and o.

then just iterate once over the source and check for each char if it is in the set! if so, add one to a counter

Comment: It would be awesome if you could format your pseudocode in a more readable way than plaintext... from skimming it it looks like a relatively simple and correct approach though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < target.length(); i++) {
    char c = target.charAt(i);
    if (c == '#') // If token then do not count
        continue;
    String cStr = String.valueOf(c);
    count += source.length() - source.replaceAll(cStr, "").length();
    target = target.replaceAll(cStr, "#"); // Trade letter for token
}
```

The char '#' acts like a token, telling that that letter was already counted in the target string.

**Update** for discussion with @Volgel612

```
int count = 0;
char last = '\0';
char[] chars = target.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    char c = chars[i];
    if (c == last)
        continue;
    String cStr = String.valueOf(c);
    count += source.length() - source.replaceAll(cStr, "").length();
    last = c;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that replacing the handled character is kind of... useless? You don't get aroind to handling it again either way....

Comment: In the case of the example provided, 'llo', the char 'l' appear two times, so the replacement was necessary to avoid using control arrays. @rolfl idea of first sorting the target string would resolve this more easily, though.

Comment: You could circumvent this by modifying a copy of source and updating that copy after every operation you perform. Counting characters would then be as simple as: `source.length() - copy.length()`. This approach would probably be faster too, as you have less newly created Strings. Additionally there's no guarantees that # isn't a valid input ...

Comment: Nah, sorting is better. With sorting I just need to check if the character repeated, if it repeated then just ignore. No need for replacing the target string (or copy). The # token could be anything, that's was just an example. With sorting it is unnecessary.

Comment: I'll update the answer so you can see.

Answer (score -2):

If you like a compact solution using regular expressions try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countChars("ooood", "Hello World"));
    System.out.println(countChars("llo", "Hello World"));
}
public static int countChars(String source, String target) {
    if (source.isEmpty()) return 0;
    String regex = "[" + source.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\").replaceAll("\\]", "\\\\]") + "]";
    return target.length() - target.replaceAll(regex, "").length();
}
```

It creates a regular expression with a character class containing all characters from target. Then it replaces all those characters in source with nothing and returns how many characters have been removed.

Comment: I don't understand in the slightest what you are trying to accomplish with the string-replace when creating the regex. Fancy adding a little explanation??

Comment: Regular expressions seems like the totally wrong tool to use here.